# A measure of non-shrinkingness of bases in Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a basis for a Banach space $X$ with biorthogonal functionals $(x^{*}_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$. We set
$$\textrm{sh}_{2}((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})=\sup_{x^{*}\in B_{X^{*}}}\limsup_{n}\|x^{*}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle x^{*},x_{i}\rangle x^{*}_{i}\|.$$ Then $(x_{n})_{n}$ is shrinking if and only if $\textrm{sh}_{2}((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})=0$. I observed that $\textrm{sh}_{2}((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})\geq 1$ for every non-shrinking basis. Furthermore, we have proved that $\textrm{sh}_{2}$ takes all possible values in the interval $[1,+\infty)$. Recently, I am thinking about the following question:

Question. Is there a basis $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $c_{0}$ with $\textrm{sh}_{2}((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty})=2K$, where $K$ is the basis constant of  $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ ?